# SimpleDateFormat parse exception on Android 7+

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to parse a date and convert to a `Timestamp`.

On Android 6 it works, but on Android 7 it throws an exception.
Can any tell me how to fix it?

```
private long getCorrectDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)");
    Date parsedDate = null;
    try {
        Logger.e("PARSE DATE : "+date);
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
    Logger.e("" + date + " TO " + timestamp.getTime());
    return timestamp.getTime();
}
```

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 15 2018 10:55:55
>   GMT+0000 (UTC)"

Comment: I dnt think u search any thing ?

Comment: Your SimpleDateFormat doesn't specify a `Locale`, so it uses the system default, instead of `Locale.ENGLISH`

Comment: show the  log  of parsed date please

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: (at offset 0) even if the Simple date format and string value are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285384/getting-error-java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-at-offset-0-even-if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input has English names for day of week and month, so you need to specify a `java.util.Locale`.

If you create a `SimpleDateFormat` without a locale, it uses the device's default. Your code only works if the default is already English, otherwise you need to specify it:

```
// use Locale.US or Locale.ENGLISH, I think both will work
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)", Locale.US);
```

Actually, if you're sure that the input is always in English, use the corresponding locale instead of relying on the defaults.

Comment: thank man , i did not know about this