# DateFormat ParseException for 2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, java-time

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`ZZ:ZZ`");
        sdf.parse("2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00");
```

I am unsure what foramt the date is in but, I am pretty sure it's yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`ZZ:ZZ` or something like that. I was guessing with the z's from
https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Timestamps%2C-Time-Zones%2C-Time-Ranges%2C-and-Date-Formats

What is the right format and how do I convert it to ms?

I have also tried

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00");
```

I am grabbing it from a minecraft json file. I refuse to use joda time as minecraft was written in java 5 originally and didn't use joda time to do it. They later updated to java 7

Comment: You don't seem to have those single quotes in the sample in the title.

Comment: alright but, could you please tell me what format the date is in? I am looking at a web json api with no documentation on this. everything else is done except this

Comment: (1) I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) The format is ISO 8601, the international standard.

Answer (score 1):

```java
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00" )
```

Never use `SimpleDateFormat` or the other terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. Your input is in one of those standard formats. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

```
     * parse them zula times. example: 2010-09-18T21:35:15.000Z
     */
    public static long parseZTime(String strTime) 
    {
        return Instant.parse(strTime).toEpochMilli();
    }
    
    /**
     * parse the offset times. example: 2015-11-10T16:43:29-0500 and 2014-05-14T17:29:23+00:00
     */
    public static long parseOffsetTime(String strTime)
    {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(strTime).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution (+1). Your `parseOffsetTime()` also accepts `2010-09-18T21:35:15.000Z`, so you don’t necessarily need two methods.

Answer (score 0):

### *java.time*

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

Since your date-time string conforms to [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can parse it directly (i.e. without using a `DateTimeFormatter`) to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println("No of milliseconds from Epoch: " + odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        // Alternatively
        System.out.println("No of milliseconds from Epoch: " + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(odt.toEpochSecond()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-16T16:27:57Z
No of milliseconds from Epoch: 1608136077000
No of milliseconds from Epoch: 1608136077000
```

### What went wrong with your answer?

1. **Use of `ZZ:ZZ` instead of a single `X`:** Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more about it. Also, I am not sure whether you have enclosed `ZZ:ZZ` within quotes, used for formatting code, just to highlight it as a code or you have really done this in actual code. Make sure you never enclose `Z` within single quotes; otherwise, it will simply mean `Z` as a character literal instead of timezone. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65471427/10819573) to understand it better.
2. Although it's not mandatory for this parsing, you should never use `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` without a `Locale`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545286/10819573) to understand it better.

**Using legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-16T16:27:57+00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println("No of milliseconds from Epoch: " + date.getTime());

        // Given below is how you can convert the legacy type, java.util.Date to the
        // modern type java.time.Instant
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        System.out.println("No of milliseconds from Epoch: " + instant.toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed Dec 16 16:27:57 GMT 2020
No of milliseconds from Epoch: 1608136077000
No of milliseconds from Epoch: 1608136077000
```

Note that the `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.