# DateTimeFormatter issue

Tags: java, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

See the following test code (java 11):

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
...
var timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now();
System.out.println(timestamp);

var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP);
var zt = timestamp.format(formatter);
System.out.println(zt);
...
```

The output:`enter code here`

```
2020-12-27T23:34:34.886272600+02:00
2021-12-27T23:34:34Z
```

Note formatted time year is **2021**. And it happens only from 27/12, probably till 31/12.

Can someone explain this to me? And how do I fix the code to get the correct formatted string?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your pattern:

1. **Use of `Y` instead of `y`**: The letter `Y` specifies `week-based-year` whereas `y` specifies `year-of-era`. However, I recommend you use `u` instead of `y` for the reasons mentioned at [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java). You would also like to check [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690443/10819573) about `week-based-year`.
2. **Enclosing `Z` by single quotes:** This is a ***blunder***. The letter `Z`
   specifies `zone-offset` and if you enclose it by single quotes, it will simply mean the literal, `Z`.

Check the [documentation page of DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about these things.

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
        // OffsetDateTime now with the default timezone of the JVM
        var timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(timestamp);

        var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP);
        var zt = timestamp.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(zt);

        // OffsetDateTime now with the timezone offset of +02:00 hours
        timestamp = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
        System.out.println(timestamp);
        zt = timestamp.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(zt);

        // Parsing a user-provided date-time
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-27T23:34:34.886272600+02:00";
        timestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
        zt = timestamp.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(zt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-27T23:44:35.531145Z
2020-12-27T23:44:35+0000
2020-12-28T01:44:35.541700+02:00
2020-12-28T01:44:35+0200
2020-12-27T23:34:34.886272600+02:00
2020-12-27T23:34:34+0200
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because of the uppercase `YYYY`. You need `yyyy` here.

`Y` means *week year*. That is the year to which the week number belongs. For example,  27 Dec 2020 is week 1 of 2021.